Why use PCA instead of manually combining feature dimensions?
Why use PCA instead of manually combining feature dimensions?
I've experimented with different datasets and plotted points using various combinations of two feature dimensions. In most cases, I can find a combination where the data points are well-separated and grouped to my satisfaction. However, I rarely see instances where applying PCA leads to significantly better separation or visualization.
Given this, what are the advantages of using PCA compared to manually selecting or combining feature dimensions? Are there cases where PCA is objectively superior, and if so, why?

PCA (Principal Component Analysis) and manually combining feature dimensions are both ways to reduce dimensionality or create new representations of data, but they differ in their goals and underlying mechanics. Here's why PCA can sometimes be superior:
1. Automatic Optimization of Variance:
Manual Selection: When you manually select dimensions, you're choosing based on intuition or trial-and-error, which might not always capture the most important features in terms of variance.
PCA: PCA automatically finds the axes (principal components) that maximize the variance in the data. The first principal component will always capture the highest variance, which can reveal patterns that aren't as obvious in the original feature space.
2. Handling High-Dimensional Data:
Manual Selection: In high-dimensional spaces, it's often infeasible to manually explore all possible combinations of feature dimensions. This approach becomes impractical when you have dozens or hundreds of features.
PCA: PCA can handle high-dimensional data efficiently, reducing the data to a smaller set of meaningful dimensions without requiring manual inspection.
3. Independence from Feature Correlations:
Manual Selection: When you combine features, you may not always account for their correlations. For example, two features might be strongly correlated and essentially represent the same information.
PCA: PCA removes redundancy by creating uncorrelated (orthogonal) principal components. This can lead to more meaningful dimensions where the new axes aren't influenced by the correlations between the original features.
4. Linear Transformation and Interpretation:
Manual Selection: You may find good combinations that visually separate data, but the resulting dimensions can be hard to interpret if they're non-linear or arbitrary.
PCA: The principal components are linear combinations of the original features and can often be interpreted in terms of the most important variables influencing the dataset.
5. Better for Complex Datasets:
Manual Selection: Works well for simple or low-dimensional datasets where intuitive combinations are effective.
PCA: Shines in more complex datasets where patterns are hidden in combinations of multiple features. It can sometimes reveal separation that manual selection misses because of the interplay between many dimensions.
6. Visualization:
Manual Selection: You can sometimes find good 2D or 3D projections manually, but this might not represent the global structure of the data.
PCA: For visualization purposes, PCA provides a systematic way to reduce the data to lower dimensions while preserving as much information (variance) as possible. This makes it a go-to tool for projecting high-dimensional data.
When is PCA objectively superior?
=> When you're dealing with high-dimensional data, manual exploration of all combinations is impractical.
=> When you're concerned about feature correlations and want to ensure the new dimensions are uncorrelated.
=> When you need a systematic approach for dimensionality reduction that guarantees maximum variance capture, making it suitable for downstream tasks (e.g., clustering, classification).
=> PCA might not always show "significant" improvement in visualization, especially in low-dimensional or well-behaved datasets. However, it excels in more complex or high-dimensional datasets where manual exploration would be difficult or misleading.
